# Javascript event not defined in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

This has been asked before but I'm still struggling to wrap my head around how to fix the error in my case. I'm new to learning Javascript/jQuery. Firefox gives an error "ReferenceError: getFirstArr is not defined". I have a simplified script of what I'm trying to do here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shindig/3ncc5xdx/114/) (to make it work, select a year button first before a month button).

The culprit seems to be the getFirstArr(videos[i]) line 28. I really don't even know what to try since my code seems correct. It works in Safari, Chrome and IE. Firefox is the odd man out. Here's a snippet of the on click event where the problem is.

```
$('.campbutton').on('click', function () {
    camp = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.campbutton').removeClass('green');
    $(this).addClass('green');
    $('#searcharea').html('<table></table>');
    var campyear = camp + year;
    var count = 1;
    var noResultCount = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            getFirstArr(videos[i]); // Firefox doesn't like this line
            function getFirstArr(video) { // prints the the array where a match is found
```

The JSFiddle will have the whole code. So my question is, why is Firefox not accepting the function call, and what needs to be changed? Any help or hints are appreciated (btw, I'm still working on getting the correct table tags to format the output correctly so the videos don't just stack on top of themselves).

Edit: The specific problem Firefox has is when the camp button is clicked, no videos load in the div. The other button events are fine.

Here's the entire code in question:

```
    var videos = [ ["string1A", "string1B", "string1C"], ["string2A", "String2B", String2C"] ];
var camp = "";
var year = "";
$('#searcharea').html('select a year button first');

$('.yearbutton').on('click', function () {
    year = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.yearbutton').removeClass('green');
    $(this).addClass('green');


});

$('.campbutton').on('click', function () {
    camp = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.campbutton').removeClass('green');
    $(this).addClass('green');
    $('#searcharea').html('<table></table>');
    var campyear = camp + year;
    var count = 1;
    var noResultCount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            getFirstArr(videos[i]);
            function getFirstArr(video) {
                if (campyear === video[j]) {
                    var pos = video.indexOf(video[j]);                  
                    $('#searcharea').append('<tr><td>' + video[(pos - pos)] + '</td>' + '<td>' + 'Composer: ' + video[(pos -pos) + 1] + '<br>' + 'Player: ' + video[(pos - pos) + 2] + '<br>' + 'Piece: ' + video[(pos - pos) + 3] + '</td>');
                } 
                else noResultCount++;                    

                if (campyear === video[j] && count % 3 === 0 && j === 4)
                    $('#searcharea').append('</tr><tr>');

                if (i === videos.lenght && j === 4)
                    $('#searcharea').append('</table>');

            }   
        }
      count++;
    }
    if (noResultCount === videos.length * 5) 
         $('#searcharea').html("No results found");



});
```

Comment: Is it just that your function is defined after you use it? i.e. should it be `functionFirstArr(video){ ... }; getFirstArr(videos[i]);`. I mean, looking at it now, you shouldn't be defining a function in a loop anyway : )

Comment: That's not valid code. Can you update your question to code that actually represents what you're working with and the problem you're facing. It's impossible for us to identify the problem otherwise. (Yes, I'm aware it's in the jsFiddle, but that's not necessarily always going to be available. All of the necessary information needs to be posted in the question.)

Comment: Also, why would you write it like this?  You are declaring getFirstArr as a new function in every loop.

Comment: @user3334871 Thanks. Defined outside of the loop before the call and it works.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Thanks. I wasn't aware that JSFiddle might not always be available. Will update.

Comment: @MatthewMoon  No problem.  And since you are new to JS/JQuery, I'll help you out a bit in future coding.  JS and Jquery are known as "dynamic" languages.  They are very reactionary, firing off their functions under certain conditions.  To program in the language, you need to think of your code as event-driven.  Always make sure you write your code in a way that everything is guaranteed to be available when your function fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3ncc5xdx/123/

Here i have moved your function to outside the loop like so, I think it works, unless I misunderstood what the issue is:

```
$('.campbutton').on('click', function () {
    camp = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.campbutton').removeClass('green');
    $(this).addClass('green');
    $('#searcharea').html('<table></table>');
    var campyear = camp + year;
    var count = 1;
    var noResultCount = 0;
    function getFirstArr(video) {
        if (campyear === video[j]) {
            var pos = video.indexOf(video[j]);                  
            $('#searcharea').append('<tr><td>' + video[(pos - pos)] + '</td>' + '<td>' + 'Composer: ' + video[(pos -pos) + 1] + '<br>' + 'Player: ' + video[(pos - pos) + 2] + '<br>' + 'Piece: ' + video[(pos - pos) + 3] + '</td>');
        } 
        else noResultCount++;                    

        if (campyear === video[j] && count % 3 === 0 && j === 4)
            $('#searcharea').append('</tr><tr>');

            if (i === videos.lenght && j === 4)
                $('#searcharea').append('</table>');    
            }   
        for (i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                getFirstArr(videos[i]);
            }
            count++;
        }
    if (noResultCount === videos.length * 5) 
     $('#searcharea').html("No results found");
});
```

So the reason that it works is that the function is now declared before it is used once. Also, its now only declared once rather than again and again in your loop. It probably works in Chrome because Chrome is pretty smart and figuring our what you were implying – but Firefox will need a slightly more strict approach.

Comment: Thank you, @Djave. As others pointed out, the function needed to be defined first (not define it in the loop). Huge thanks.